# How to let the type get full info of T?

Tags: java, generics, gson, typetoken

I have the class like this:

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T>{
...
    private final Type typeInfo = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType();
}
```

The typeInfo is the same as  `new TypeToken<List>() {}.getType()` because T is not usable at runtime.

Now I would like to pass the class info by constructor parameter:

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
    private final Type typeInfo;

    GsonRequest(Class<?> c){
         //how to create a type info which equals 
         //new TypeToken<List<C>>() {}.getType() here?
    }
}
```

So,how to crete type info by this way?

Comment: What library / import do you get `TypeToken` from?  There's more than a few.

Comment: I'm assuming it's `com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken`.

Comment: And I also assume that `C` (as in `TypeToken<List<C>>` should be `T`?

Comment: yes,It's com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.I want use it this way :when i pass String or User parameter,it is able to parse List<String> or List<User>.

Comment: What if you turn GsonRequest(Class<?> c), into GsonRequest(Class<T> c)?  I do not have access to my IDE to test it out.